# Upload to business YouTube channel instead of personal channel

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube

I created a business channel with my Gmail account and then accidentally also created a personal Google+ account with the same Gmail address.
I can toggle back and forth between these two accounts, but I can't upload to my business channel anymore from my iPad.

Any suggestions? I don't want to delete either account.
I have tried signing in on my YouTube app and toggling to my business channel before uploading, but it still sends the videos to my personal page.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is log out of both accounts, then log back in in the order of importance, in your case Business, then Personal. This should make the app default to business.